# Elastic query bool must match issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, openshift, devops

Below is the query part in `Elastic` GET API via command line inside `openshift` pod , i get all the match query as well as unmatch element in the fetch of 2000 documents. how can i limit to only the match element.
i want to specifically get `{\"kubernetes.container_name\":\"xyz\"}}` only.

any suggestions will be appreciated

```
-d ' {\"query\": { \"bool\" :{\"must\" :{\"match\" :{\"kubernetes.container_name\":\"xyz\"}},\"filter\" : {\"range\": {\"@timestamp\": {\"gte\": \"now-2m\",\"lt\": \"now-1m\"}}}}},\"_source\":[\"@timestamp\",\"message\",\"kubernetes.container_name\"],\"size\":2000}'"
```

Answer (score 1):

For exact matches there are two things you would need to do:

- Make use of [Term Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)
- Ensure that the field is of type [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) datatype.

[Text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) datatype goes through [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) phase.

For e.g. if you data is `This is a beautiful day`, during ingestion, `text` datatype would break down the words into tokens, lowercase them `[this, is, a, beautiful, day]` and then add them to the inverted index. This process happens via [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which is the default analyzer applied on text field.

So now when you query, it would again apply the analyzer at *querying time* and would search if the words are present in the respective documents. As a result you see documents *even without* exact match appearing.

In order to do an exact match, you would need to make use of `keyword` fields as it *does not* goes through the analysis phase.

What I'd suggest is to create a keyword sibling field for text field that you have in below manner and then re-ingest all the data:

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_sample_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "kubernetes":{
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "container_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields":{               <--- Note this
              "keyword":{            <--- This is container_name.keyword field
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I'm assuming you are making use of `object` type.

### Request Query:

```
POST my_sample_index
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "kubernetes.container_name.keyword": {
              "value": "xyz"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, on what basis are you saying that one should avoid using `bool` and `must` clause if the query is straightforward and simple? I mentioned that because OP has used bool query in the question. And even if he did not, I'd suggest him to start using one because that would help him create much more complex queries in future, which I think is a decent advice for new comers in ES.

Comment: Got it. But do you understand exact match and what it means? The value should not be modified by ES. That is the whole point. Sure, working with text and having everything lowercase *makes it appears* to be working it like that, but semantically that is **not right**. Also what about multiple string values. Either way it is not right solution. I would never advise anyone to use `text` fields using match query or worse term query for exact match. And lastly, I simply don't understand why do you think changing mapping is going to be bad?

Comment: Never mind. I am convinced by my answer and I truly feel obligated to let users know on the correct way to provide the solution and not a temporary work around. Also using Bool query is in no way going to reduce simplicity and clarity. It is self explainable and would allow user to explore more on Query DSL of ES. Have a good day, Sir!!

Comment: Again that's an assumption that you have saying that its is a single token. OP has not specified that plus he indicated that he is seeing more results than what he wants. Don't you think that is because it is not functioning as an exact match. ES has specifically mentioned as a *warning* section in their link for Term Query, please do not use text field for term query. It is simply not the right solution. I understand what you are saying but there are use cases where what you'd suggest won't work that way.

Comment: And I absolutely do not agree with your solution as it can lead to leaks in the future :) I'm happy that I've provided an efficient and correct solution to the OP. Have a nice day, Sir!!